# AngularJS programatically call filter from service (sort by custom filter)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, sorting, filter

I have a the following situation (a translation filter in a service, used in the HTML file)

```js
// serviceFile
angular.module('myModule')
  .service('translation')
  .filter('translate', function(translation) {
    // translate stuff
    return 'translatedString';
  });

// controllerFile
angular.module('myModule')
  .controller('StringsController', function(blabla, translation) {
    $scope.mySort = function() {
      return "some magic should happen here";
    };
  });

// htmlFile
<tr ng-repeat="string in strings">
  <td> 
      {{ string | translate: 'name' }} 
  </td>
</tr>
```

(The above code works, but perhaps some vital parts were omitted due to my lack of experience)

My issue is that I am requested to sort based on the translated values (something like `string in strings | orderBy: mySearch`) and I can't find how to call the filter programatically from the `StringsController.mySearch`

P.S. the filter is not returned from the service (don't know if this is relevant)

Comment: you need inject _$filter_ and use it like `$filter('translation')(params)`

Comment: @Grundy, can you give me a newbie link ? I only used very basic angularjs and the service is not even my code. I don't even know if I should inject it into the controller or the service ?

Comment: also see [guid for filters](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/filter)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can see [guide for filters](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/filter)

So in your case depends from defininition `.filter('translate',` you can use it like

```
.controller('StringsController', function(blabla, $filter) {
    //simple transtale
    var translatedString = $filter('translate')(stringForTranslate);

    //ordering
    var ordered = $filter('orderBy')(arrayForOrdering,function(el){ return  $filter('translate')(el); })

});
```

Comment: I've added the $scope.mySearch = function(string) { return $filter('translate')(string); } to the controller, and also the $fitler at the beginning... my only problem remaining is how to get to the 'name'... btw thanks for the help so far..

Comment: can you provide a complex sample? possibly with [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) or [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/), here a show a basic method, how you can filter and order in your controller

Comment: while doing the jsfiddle i found the solution... had to modify to $filter('translate')(stringForTranslate, 'name'); thanks for all the help

Comment: @norb, also i'm a bit confused your sample filter declaration, so it return not string, but function like `function (string, param)` where inside `return 'translatedString';`